# jQuery json remove element from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do i remove an specific json object from input value?

i have tried this [jquery javascript remove object data from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187337/jquery-javascript-remove-object-data-from-json-object) and used splice.

it didnt remove the object from input value.

html:

```
<input type="text" name="jsonKey" value='{"keyId":"1","price":"13.28"},{"keyId":"2","price":"15.00"}' style="width:100%">
 <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    var json = $.parseJSON('[' + $('input[name=jsonKey]').val() + ']');

    $.each(json, function(index, result) {
       if(result['keyId'] == 1) {
           //delete json[index];
           //json.splice(index,1);
      }
   });

   return false;
  });
```

you can check the code http://jsfiddle.net/Pwa92/

Comment: You are not updating the value.

Comment: @Felix how to update the value?

Comment: `$('input[name=jsonKey]').val(JSON.stringify(json))`

Answer (score 1):

Based on Imrul's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery), you can use `$.grep`:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
    var json = $.parseJSON('[' + $('input[name=jsonKey]').val() + ']');

    console.log(json);

    json = jQuery.grep(
        json, 
        function (item,index) { 
            return item.keyId !=  "1"; 
        }
    );

    console.log(json);

   return false;
});
```

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pwa92/8/), use it with browser's js console open.