# Remove elements where no match in a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, collections, filter

I have the following structure -

```
{  
   "fruits":[  
      {  
         "name":"apples",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {  
         "name":"pears",
         "id":"4"
      },
      {  
         "name":"grapes",
         "id":"5"
      }
   ],
   "links":[  
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"4",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"9",
         "target":"10"
      },
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"10"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to remove the section of the **links** where source and target are equal to (9 and 10) and (1 and 10).

This has to be removed as the aforementioned **does not match** a combination of any of the id's in the **fruits** section.

So I have tried to iterate over each link element however stuck on how to check against each id in the fruits object -

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {

               // logic 
}
```

I think it would be along the lines of -

```
if(data.links[i].source || data.links[i].target) // something
```

So if `data.links[i].source || data.links[i].target` DO NOT MATCH a combination of any of the ID's in the fruits object then -

```
delete data.links[i];
```

So remove -

```
  {  
     "source":"9",
     "target":"10"
  },
  {  
     "source":"1",
     "target":"10"
  }
```

Because neither 9 or 10 are present AT ALL in the fruits object (therefore remove) and although 1 DOES exist, 10 doesn't, therefore it doesn't match a combination of any of the ids in the fruit object so again remove.

How can I achieve the resulting structure -

```
{  
       "fruits":[  
          {  
             "name":"apples",
             "id":"1"
          },
          {  
             "name":"pears",
             "id":"4"
          },
          {  
             "name":"grapes",
             "id":"5"
          }
       ],
       "links":[  
          {  
             "source":"1",
             "target":"5"
          },
          {  
             "source":"4",
             "target":"5"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to iterate through the `fruits` array with each element of `links`, and check the `source` and `target` against the `id` of each fruit. If at least one doesn't match, remove the element from `links`. This could be implemented as so:

```
for (var i = data.links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var sourceExists = false;
    var targetExists = false;

    // Check source and target against each fruit id
    for (var j = 0; j < data.fruits.length; j++){
        if (data.links[i].source == data.fruits[j].id){
            sourceExists = true;
        }
        if (data.links[i].target == data.fruits[j].id){
            targetExists = true;
        }
    }

    // Remove element if either source or target didn't match
    if (!sourceExists || !targetExists){
        data.links.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Note how I iterate backwards through the `links` array, since removal of an element could otherwise have unwanted side effects while iterating forwards. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcm8etbw/) to demonstrate my solution.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Glad I could help! I wish the downvoter could indicate where I went wrong, however...

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove(obj) {

    // get list of fruit ids
    var fruitsIds = obj.fruits.map(function (obj) { return obj.id; });

    // loop over the links array
    for (var i = 0, l = obj.links.length; i < l; i++) {
        var el = obj.links[i];

        // if either the source or target id is not found in the fruitsId
        // array, remove the object and recalculate the size of the links array
        if (fruitsIds.indexOf(el.source) === -1 || fruitsIds.indexOf(el.target) === -1) {
            obj.links.splice(i, 1);
            l--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yf9pvL48/)

Answer (score 0):

To remove an entry from an array without leaving a gap in the array, you use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) rather than `delete`. The first argument is the index of the entry, and the second argument is how many to delete starting with that index.

So:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < data.links.length) {
    if (yourDeletionConditionGoesHere) {
        // Delete this one
        data.links.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        // We didn't delete it, so move to the next
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first build an array of all the `id` properties of your `fruits`,
then test if each link's `target` & `source` property are in that list.

- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
function rm (j) {
  var flist = j.fruits.map(function (o) {
    return o.id;
  });
  
  j.links = j.links.filter(function (o) {
    return flist.indexOf(o.source) > -1 &&
           flist.indexOf(o.target) > -1; 
  });
  
  return j;
}

var jso = {  
   "fruits":[  
      {  
         "name":"apples",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {  
         "name":"pears",
         "id":"4"
      },
      {  
         "name":"grapes",
         "id":"5"
      }
   ],
   "links":[  
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"4",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"9",
         "target":"10"
      },
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"10"
      }
   ]
};


console.log(rm(jso));
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is already given here :

[jquery javascript remove object data from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187337/jquery-javascript-remove-object-data-from-json-object)

You only need to split the json data in the question `val.zipcode` and the value it needs to be compared to `"yourvalue"`